# What does size of the GRU or LSTM cell in the TensorFlow seq2seq tutorial represent?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working with the [seq2seq model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py) in the [TensorFlow tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq), and I'm having trouble understanding some of the details. One thing that is confusing to me is what the "size" of a cell represents. I think I have a high level understanding of images like [image: seq2seq diagram]

I believe this is showing that the output from the last step in the encoder is the input to the first step in the encoder. In this case each box is the GRU or LSTM cell at a different time-step in the sequence.

I also think I understand, at a superficial level, diagrams like this:
[image: GRU Cell diagram] from [colah's blog post about LSTM and GRU cells](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/). My understanding is that a "cell" is a neural network that feeds the output from one step back into itself along with the new input for the subsequent step. The gates control how much it "remembers" and "forgets."

I think I am getting confused at the level between this superficial, high level understanding and the low-level details. It sounds like the "size" of a cell is the number of nodes in the sigmoid and tanh boxes. Is that correct? If so, how does that relate to the input size for the seq2seq model? For example, the default vocabulary size is 40,000, and the default cell size is 1024. How does the 40,000 element one-hot vocabulary vector for each step of the sequence get matched to the 1024 node internal cell size? Is that what the embedding wrapper does?

Most importantly, what effect would increasing or decreasing the size of the cell have? Would a larger cell be better at learning embeddings? Or at predicting outputs? Both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It sounds like the "size" of a cell is the number of nodes in the
>   sigmoid and tanh boxes. Is that correct?

The size of the cell is the size of the RNN state vector *h*. In the case of LSTM it's also the size of *c*. It's not "the number of nodes" (I'm not sure what you mean by nodes).

> If so, how does that relate to the input size for the seq2seq model?
>   For example, the default vocabulary size is 40,000, and the default
>   cell size is 1024. How does the 40,000 element one-hot vocabulary
>   vector for each step of the sequence get matched to the 1024 node
>   internal cell size?

The input size for the model is independent of the state size. The two vectors (input and state) are concatenated and multiplied by a matrix of shape [state_size + input_size, state_size] to get the next state (simplified version).

> Is that what the embedding wrapper does?

No, the embedding is the result of multiplying the 1-hot input vector with a matrix of size [vocab_size, input_size], before doing the multiplication.